# I need to draw the chemical Structural Formula of paxlitaxel in latex

Tags: chemfig

I need to draw the chemical Structural Formula of paxclitaxel in latex

Comment: Try [`chemfig`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemfig?lang=en)

Comment: Could you add some more details? What is "paxclitaxel"?

Comment: @Bobyandbob https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paclitaxel

Comment: @Asmaa: If this is meant seriously, could you correct the spelling in the question or tell us the meaning of paxlitaxel? If you just want to include a structural formula of paclitaxel, you might download https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Taxol.svg, convert it with inkscape into a pdf file and than use \includegraphics.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 1):

**Paclitaxel**: chemical Structural Formula.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    \chemfig{
                 % 1
        -[:264.4]% 2
       =_[:325.3]% 3
          -[:345]% 4
                    (
             <[:52.5]O% 59
            -[:112.5]% 60
                        (
                 -[:52.5]% 62
                        )
            =[:172.5]O% 61
                    )
          -[:300]% 5
                    (
              =[:7.5]O% 6
                    )
          -[:255]% 7
                    (
             <[:22.5]% 58
                    )
          -[:330]% 8
                    (
           <[:30,,,1]OH% 57
                    )
          -[:270]% 9
          >[:210]% 10
          -[:150]% 11
                    (
              -[:240]% 51
              -[:330]O% 52
               -[:60]% -> 10
                    )
                    (
             <:[:175]O% 53
              -[:235]% 54
                        (
                  -[:295]% 56
                        )
              =[:175]O% 55
                    )
           >[:90]% 12
                    (
               -[:30]% -> 7
                    )
          -[:165]% 13
                    (
           <:[:232.5]O% 42
            -[:172.5]% 43
                        (
                -[:232.5]% 45
               =_[:292.5]% 46
                -[:232.5]% 47
               =_[:172.5]% 48
                -[:112.5]% 49
                =_[:52.5]% 50
                -[:352.5]% -> 45
                        )
            =[:112.5]O% 44
                    )
          -[:120]% 14
                    (
               -[:75]% 15
                        (
                  -[:170]% 16
                        )
                        (
                  -[:115]% 17
                        )
               -[:30]% -> 3
                    )
                    (
        <[:219.8,,,2]HO% 41
                    )
        -[:139.7]% 18
         -[:81.6]% 19
                    (
             -[:23.4]% -> 2
                    )
       <:[:142.5]O% 20
        -[:202.5]% 21
                    (
            =[:262.5]O% 22
                    )
        -[:142.5]% 23
                    (
         <[:82.5,,,1]OH% 40
                    )
        -[:202.5]% 24
                    (
            -[:142.5]% 25
           =_[:202.5]% 26
            -[:142.5]% 27
            =_[:82.5]% 28
             -[:22.5]% 29
           =_[:322.5]% 30
            -[:262.5]% -> 25
                    )
    <[:262.5,,,1]NH% 31
     -[:202.5,,1]% 32
                    (
            =[:142.5]O% 33
                    )
        -[:262.5]% 34
       =_[:322.5]% 35
        -[:262.5]% 36
       =_[:202.5]% 37
        -[:142.5]% 38
        =_[:82.5]% 39
                    (
             -[:22.5]% 
                    )
}
\end{document}
```